# li class active page

Tags: javascript, html

I can add it with the code I wrote in nav menu a, but I want to add it to li class instead of a href. and I want this event to start at the beginning of the page.

normally when I use it like this now, the page does not write active. I will be very happy if you can help.

```html
<div class="middle_right right header_side">
  <div class="header_side_container">
    <div class="header_builder_component header_builder_menu_component">
      <nav class="main-menu main_menu_container menu_line_enable">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1032">
            <a href="home.php"><span>Home</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1033">
            <a href="videos.php"><span>videos</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1034">
            <a href="gallery.php">
              <span>gallery</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1035">
            <a href="about.php">
              <span>about</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1036">
            <a href="contact.php">
              <span>contact</span>
            </a>
          </li>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function updateMenu(url) {
  const active = document.querySelector('.main-menu a.active');
  if (active !== null) {
    active.classList.remove('active');
  }

  const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.main-menu a'));
  const index = links.map(link => link.href).findIndex((href) => {
    return url.indexOf(href) !== -1;
  });

  if (index !== -1) {
    links[index].classList.add('active');
  }
}

barba.hooks.before((data) => {
  updateMenu(data.trigger.href);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the anchors, you can loop through the list items, and grab the anchor within the list item, and compare the URLs and add the active class to the list item as needed.

For this, `map` isn't needed, you can use a normal `foreach` and an `if` statement.

```
    <div class="middle_right right header_side">
    <div class="header_side_container">
    <div class="header_builder_component header_builder_menu_component">
    <nav class="main-menu main_menu_container menu_line_enable">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1032">
    <a href="home.php"><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1033">
    <a href="videos.php"><span>videos</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1034">
    <a href="gallery.php">
    <span>gallery</span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1035">
    <a href="about.php">
    <span>about</span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1036">
    <a href="contact.php">
    <span>contact</span>
    </a>
    </li>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    function updateMenu(url) {
            const active = document.querySelector('.menu-item.active');
    
            if (active !== null) {
                active.classList.remove('active');
            }
    
            const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item'));

            links.forEach(function(li){
               let anchor = li.querySelector("a");
               if(url.indexOf(anchor.href) > -1){
                   li.classList.add("active");
                }
            });
        }

      updateMenu(window.location.href);

   /* barba.hooks.before((data) => {
            updateMenu(data.trigger.href);
        });
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when you write, there is no code deletion event. Active class remained in li classes I clicked.

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is not activated according to the URL open at the time of opening the page.

Comment: @KaanDemir I updated my answer by disabling your `barba` code and added in a different call to `updateMenu`

Comment: I accepted your answer. Well, would it be a problem if I used the barba under it?

Comment: @KaanDemir I have no idea what the barba code is, but if it passes the correct href, you can use it instead of the call `updateMenu(window.location.href);`.

Comment: barba js library to allow the page to pass without refreshing. It worked fine, there was no problem. do you have the opportunity to look at the new topic?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63254686/nav-li-span-margin-left